# Collect Syslog data with Rsyslog off of Network TAP

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to collect forwarded UDP syslog data with *Rsyslog* (v8.24) that is passed over a passive optical tap.

Rsyslog server: IP `10.10.35.15`, configured to listen for UDP syslog on port `514`.

Syslog generating server: IP `10.10.25.120`, exists in a separate network from the Rsyslog server. It is sending its syslog to `10.10.35.15` over a network TAP to the switch where the syslog traffic is dropped.

I have configured the Rsyslog server, I have been able to successfully forward logs to the syslog server from other servers within the same network (`10.10.35.x`). I have not been able to forward traffic from my test device in the other network to my Rsyslog server. I have run tcpdump on the Rsyslog server and I have observed test messages come across the NIC. I have tried running  the NIC in standard mode and promiscuous mode with no success.

Any thoughts as to why Rsyslog is not writing the remote syslog to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up figuring it out. As I mentioned previously I could see the test traffic on the interface but nothing was being written to syslog. I made my rsyslog.conf file as simple as I could and I still had no results. After thinking about it, reading your comments & noticing that TCPdump would consistently mention dropped packets I took another look at the networking.

I was sending the Syslog to a switch in order to capture the traffic with a TAP. I took the MAC address of the port on the switch and changed the MAC of the NIC on the the Rsyslog collector to the MAC of the switch port. This didn't work, however, I noticed in Wireshark the MAC from the switch was an HSRP MAC. I ended up forwarding Syslog to another server in the network & I gave my Rsyslog collecter the MAC & IP of that device. This allowed Rsyslog to write the remote logs to a file.

I'm not quite sure what is going on, I think the OS was ignoring the traffic due to the fact the destination MAC was not the same MAC as the NIC I using for monitoring. I'm sure not a lot of folks find themselves in the situation I did but I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

first step for me would be to compare the two different situations you describe above in tcpdump output:

A) your syslog server receives a syslog packet from another server in the same network 10.10.35.x

B) your syslog server receives a syslog packet from your generating server (10.10.25.120)

The one piece of information I would check first is the ethernet hardware destination address on the ethernet frames carrying these packets.

In case A) that should clearly be the hardware address of your rsyslog server, which the other server in the same network has most likely learned via a preceding ARP request.

In case B) I'm not exactly sure what to expect. My guess would be that it is the hardware address of the default router in your generating network, where your generating server 10.10.25.120 has probably realized from the IP address of your rsyslog destination server that that guy is not on his local network, i.e. routing is required. Then somewhere on the way to your default router inside 10.10.25.x there is your TAP which acts like a wormhole :-) by duplicating that ethernet frame over into the 10.10.35.x network. On your rsyslog server you can see that frame with TCPdump in case your network card is in promiscuous mode (because the frame still carries the ethernet hardware destination address of the default router in 10.10.25.x) but the  UDP socket listening on port 514 for your rsyslog software may not get forwarded the packet from inside that frame by the rsyslog server's kernel networking code because the hardware destination address of that frame does not match any hardware address of the rsyslog NIC.

In other words, the fact that you can see traffic "on the wire" with tcpdump running at your destination showing the correct destination IP address may not guarantee that this packet is really delivered to the higher layers inside your destination machine.

Hope this helps a bit....

Comment: Eradian,

Thanks for your insight. After stewing on this for a couple of days I've come to a similar conclusion.

Comment: You are welcome, there may be specific tricks how you could still achieve this, possibly via a dedicated entries in your routing table and arp table on 10.10.25.120. It may depend a bit on the physical location of your tap and possible intermediate layer2 switches. PS: Maybe you want to consider voting on my answer :-)